# How does the anchor tag (<a>) lets you do an Reflected XSS?

Tags: xss

I was going through the [OWASP XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet and](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) and I came across [this section](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Google_.22feeling_lucky.22_part_1.) where there is an anchor tag used to do an XSS in the following forms:

```
<A HREF="//google">XSS</A>
<A HREF="http://ha.ckers.org@google">XSS</A>
<A HREF="http://google:ha.ckers.org">XSS</A>
```

I can imagine its use in a stored XSS attacks (like some forum post saying "Click me") but I cannot imagine its use in a Reflected XSS attack. Can anyone tell if it's possible to do a reflected XSS using the anchor tag? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is information used to form the link itself, then it can be done: Imagine a page: *http://site.com/redirect.php?target=google.com* which will show one of those "You are leaving site.com, we're not responsible... click here to ...".  It may put part of your URI (the target parameter) into the HTML code.

If you'd try to escape this with "*google.com"%20onclick="alert(document.cookie)*", you could form the following:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="alert(document.cookie)">
```

Of course, there are many if's - but it can be done.

Comment: The OWASP document stated `Assuming "http://www.google.com/" is pro grammatically [sic] disallowed` meaning that anything starting with that string would not be accepted. The document is discussing URL blacklisting rather than how to escape out of a quoted `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible as long as a site uses non-persistant data to construct an anchor tag without properly sanitizing the data.  A contrived example:

```
<a href="/whatever?s={Write unsanitized query string value here}">{or maybe here?}</a>
```

That being said, the link that you posted has to do with URL string evasion and not reflected XSS.  Is it possible you are confused on what reflected XSS is?  Or possibly I just misunderstood your question :)

Comment: Na. What you wrote non-persistant data being used to create a query tag answers my question. But I had to accept one answer and the other answer seemed close enough. So, just upvoting it.

Comment: Not every XSS is remediated by proper encoding of the HTML output.  In particular, if the anchor's href attribute's value is generated entirely from an input, the latter needs white-listing for reflection of only authorized URLs or, at least, for reflection of URLs starting with https://.  This is because reflecting javascript:alert(1) in href is dangerous due to abusing the trust in clickable links rather than abusing the insufficient encapuslation of input on output.